# Can a 32bit only MacOS Application use 64bit-only Frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks, 32bit-64bit

Our Mac application can (sadly) only build and run in 32bit-only. Reason is: a huge bunch of very old 32bit-only C++ code shared with other platforms (Windows, Android, Linux, etc.). This is cross server-client networking-protocol code, so it can't really be replaced. Until EVERYONE needs is 64bit, we're bound to build our app 32bit only.

Now I'm building a new module for this application as an external private dynamic framework. I'd like to use ARC, and the new niceties of modern Obj-C runtime, but these are only available in 64bit-only builds.

So… Could my 32bit Mac Application link, and use, and load a 64bit-only framework?

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow answers of two letters only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer, which is on the whole --- **NO**.

Here are the details, and a work-around.

First off, a 32bit process can’t load 64bit code. The linker complains when you try to link the 64bit-only framework to your 32bit app.

I was offered two ways around this, both rely on parting the 32bit-only code and the 64bit-only code into 2 different processes, talking using XPC.

The first way would be to create a "host" 64bit process that will load my 64bit framework, and the 32bit application can then use XPC to talk to it.

The second option would be to extract all the 64bit-unsafe code (things I MUST compile 32bit-only) and put THAT in a special 32bit-only process then I can make my application 64bit only on Mac, add the new framework, and talk via XPC to the 32bit helper process.